# Need advice about preventing my LaCie Cloudbox to get assigned a new IP with every reboot or shut down - as it messes up port-forwarding

Tags: router

Hi there you sweet good people.
I have this so called VDSL connection – and got this absolutely WONDERFUL technicolor (TG589vn v2) router to use (I hope everyone did spot the sarcasm ;-).
I just bought LaCie cloudbox (3TB, not that the size matters in case however), and In order to use the FTP feature of the „server“ I of course have to forward ports from the router to the cloudbox. E.g. port 21 (TCP) and so on and so on. Everything works great after I put in the port forwarding rules into the router – and the cloud works perfectly! But then I have this HIGHLY annoying problem which describes in that:
-   every time that I turn the cloud off when (e.g.) leaving town for some time, or simply when I have to reboot the cloud -> then the LaCie Cloudbox is assigned a new local IP address, which (obviously I guess) leads to that the cloud becomes unreachable via remote access as the port-forwarding no longer points to the cloud.
•   This happens even though the „device“, or simply the cloud is automatically configured by the router to ALWAYS use the same IP address. The cloud itself is likewise configured (manually) to always use the IP address I configured.
Can someone PLEASE point out what I could be doing wrong here? I would be very glad if I wouldn‘t have to login to the router over and over again to point this port-forwarding to the new IP address that for some reason automatically gets assigned to it.
All suggestions are very much appreciated, and to all of you who spent your time reading all this – thank you very much for doing so!
Best regards, and a very big thanks in advance to you guys!

Comment: To be clear, you are saying you configured a static IP address in the Cloudbox and it still sometimes switches to some other address?

Comment: Reading the guide at http://help.telecom.co.nz/app/answers/detail/a_id/32667/~/technicolor-tg589vn-v2---help-%26-support  it appears to me that you might've enabled dynamicDNS;  in that case, you'd want to access via the hostname instead, and that should always get you to the device.